# optimising GAE/J backup and restore in a multi-tenancy application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, namespaces, google-cloud-storage

I have a multi-tenancy GAE/J application and have implemented a cron-based nightly backup to Google Cloud Storage.  Backing up seems easy and cheap with 15GB of total data comprising mainly indexes.

However, after running a test-restore I have several observations and am looking for recommendations.

1. My backup / restore strategy involves restoring from only one namespace, but GAE does not allow specifying a namespace in during restore (though it does for backups).
2. I'm obliged to restore all my data to an intermediary application I created for this purpose.
3. The plan involves doing a secondary backup of the missing Entities in whichever Namespace has suffered the data loss.
4. Finally a restore of that specific data set to my live application.

The above works, but it is:

1. Expensive: I pay for a restore which will contain mainly unwanted namespaces.
2. Time consuming

A workaround is specifying backups of each Namespace separately so I can access them independently if required.  But I don't really like the idea of having to maintain my list of namespaces somewhere.

I read about GAEBAR but understand it doesn't apply to Java applications.

I'm curious to know if anyone else has any practical experience / recommendations in this area?

(of course the best solution would be if Google supported restore of a single NS from within a multi-namespace Cloud Backup)

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't quite understand, are you implementing the backup/restore logic yourself or using the builtin feature? What do you mean by "however you can't specify namespace in a restore "

Answer (score 0):

> My backup / restore strategy involves restoring from only one
>   namespace, but GAE does not allow specifying a namespace in during
>   restore (though it does for backups).

That's because the namespace is encoded in the key of the entity. If you supply only the object that is in a certain namespace, only those entities will be updated.

> But I don't really like the idea of having to maintain my list of
>   namespaces somewhere.

You can query this kind "**namespace**" and it will show you a list of namespaces

```
SELECT * FROM __namespace__
```